# Pagination in codeigniter with duplicate entry error

Tags: pagination, codeigniter-3

I have implemented the pagination in codeigniter.But the result is not the expected one.I have 5 entries.1,2,3,4,5.
This is my controller

```
$this->data['models_num']=$this->model_models->getModels_ImageData();
$model=$this->data['models_num'];
$row=count($model);
$this->data['brands']=$this->model_brands->getBrandsData();
$config['base_url'] = base_url('services/NewCar');
$config['total_rows'] = $row;
$config['per_page'] = 4;
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$this->data['models'] = $this->model_models->getModels_ImageDataPage($config["per_page"], $page);
$config['num_links'] = $row;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

My model is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM models LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start";
```

The problem is that
When i try for the first page.,it shows 4 entires.That ok.but whwn i clcxik the second page it shows 3 enties.That two rows are duplicated. that first page 1,2,3,4 entries are diaplayed. And in second page 3,4,5 are ipalyed.Please help.Pleaseee

Answer (score 0):

In these cases it's a good idea to put some numbers in and visualise what is going on...

So taking your sql statement

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM models LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start";
```

**$limit** will be the number of items you wish to retrieve.
**$start** is where it will start getting them from.

When $page is 0 ie no number is given on the first time
$start will be 0. So you will get 1,2,3,4

When $page = 2,
$start will be 2, So you will get 3,4,5 as the offset is now 2. i.e it starts reading from the 3rd position in the database.

What you are expecting is that the 2nd page should start at the 5th element so it should give 5,6,7,8.

The issue here is that your offset is not correct. It needs to be the **page number * the number of entries**.

The quick fix is to change your existing code from...

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$this->data['models'] = $this->model_models->getModels_ImageDataPage($config["per_page"], $page);
```

to

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 1;
$this->data['models'] = $this->model_models->getModels_ImageDataPage($config["per_page"], ($page -1) * $config["per_page"]);
```

**The changes are**

1. Set the default value of your url segment to 1
2. Change the value for $start (offset) to be `($page -1) * $config["per_page"]`

So when there is no page, $page will be 1 (the same when it is actually page 1).

```
       Offset
Page   ($page - 1 ) * $config["per_page"]  Entries
1        (1 - 1) * 4 = 0                   1,2,3,4
2        (2 - 1) * 4 = 4                   5,6,7,8
3        (3 - 1) * 4 = 8                   9,10,11,12
4        (4 - 1) * 4 = 12                  13,14,15,16
```

and so on...